# How do you extract tag values and selector with Scrapy? as opposed to the tag content

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape a site that is not ideally structured.  Information within one set of tags is required to understand information in another set of tags, but the second set of tags are not nested within the first; nor is there a containing tag to group sets of data.  Rather they are placed sequentially, and on some of the pages there are a lot of tables of data that need to be married up to the headers, which are in separate list tags.

Hence using a 'for loop' of the kind:

> for myitem in response.xpath('*')
> does not quite do the trick.

if I do the following in scrapy shell

```
>>> products = response.xpath('//*[@class="r"]//*')
>>> len(products)
271
>>> products[5]
<Selector xpath='//*[@class="r"]//*' data='<ul class="list">\n                   ...'>
>>> products[5].xpath('@class')
```

I get:

```
[<Selector xpath='@class' data='list'>]
```

if I then try an if statement:

```
>>> if products[5].xpath('@class') == 'list': "it works!"
...
>>>
```

It doesn't work;  similarly, the following also does not work, and I have tried many other things:

```
>>> if products[5].xpath('@class') == '<Selector xpath='@class' data='list'>': "it works!"
  File "<console>", line 1
    if products[5].xpath('@class') == '<Selector xpath='@class' data='list'>': "it works!"
                                                         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

What I would want to do, is to loop through products with and for each html tag, set it against an if clause; such as if div and class= 'a' then do this, if table and id='b' then do that.  But I am unable.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you please provide an example of what you are referring to?

Comment: well, I have a script that will loop through numerous html tags, of all different types, and I want to be able to identify what each tag is, I want to return the selector type, and/or the tag class, and/or the tag id.  I've been doing a lot of research, I can find endless information about how to return what is contained between tags, but not returning what the tag is.

Comment: for example, for a list tag I was wanting something like   if products[5].xpath('@class') == 'list': "it works!"

Comment: No I meant like a url or html snippet that demonstrates the issue you are facing. @user2115136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to query the class you almost got it, all you need to do is add the `.get()` to the xpath query to extract the text for it to work the way you want.  To query the html tag the only way I know of to do this is to use the `Selector.re` method to extract the tag name.

Here is an example that demonstrates both.

```
In [1]: fetch("https://quotes.toscrape.com")
2023-07-30 21:57:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-07-30 21:57:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://quotes.toscrape.com> (referer: None)

In [2]: for element in response.xpath("//*"):
   ...:     print("element = ", element)
   ...:     print("element class = ", element.xpath("./@class").get())
   ...:     print("element tag = ", element.re(r"^<(\w+?)\s"))
   ...:     print()
   ...:
element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<html lang="en">\n<head>\n\t<meta charse...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['html']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<head>\n\t<meta charset="UTF-8">\n\t<titl...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta charset="UTF-8">'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<title>Quotes to Scrape</title>'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['link']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['link']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<body>\n    <div class="container">\n  ...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="container">\n        <div ...'>
element class =  container
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="row header-box">\n        ...'>
element class =  row header-box
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="col-md-8">\n              ...'>
element class =  col-md-8
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<h1>\n                    <a href="/" ...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/" style="text-decoration: n...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="col-md-4">\n              ...'>
element class =  col-md-4
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<p>\n                \n                ...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/login">Login</a>'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="row">\n    <div class="col...'>
element class =  row
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="col-md-8">\n\n    <div clas...'>
element class =  col-md-8
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“T...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(ab...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/change/page...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/deep-though...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/thinking/pa...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/world/page/...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“I...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/J-K-Rowling">(about)...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/abilities/p...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/choices/pag...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“T...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(ab...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/inspiration...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/life/page/1...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/live/page/1...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/miracle/pag...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/miracles/pa...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“T...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Jane-Austen">(about)...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/aliteracy/p...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/books/page/...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/classic/pag...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/humor/page/...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“I...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Marilyn-Monroe">(abo...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/be-yourself...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/inspiration...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“T...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(ab...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/adulthood/p...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/success/pag...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/value/page/...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“I...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Andre-Gide">(about)</a>'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/life/page/1...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/love/page/1...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“I...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Thomas-A-Edison">(ab...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/edison/page...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/failure/pag...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/inspiration...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/paraphrased...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“A...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Eleanor-Roosevelt">(...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/misattribut...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype...'>
element class =  quote
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="text" itemprop="text">“A...'>
element class =  text
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span>by <small class="author" itempr...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<small class="author" itemprop="autho...'>
element class =  author
element tag =  ['small']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/author/Steve-Martin">(about...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="tags">\n            Tags:\n...'>
element class =  tags
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<meta class="keywords" itemprop="keyw...'>
element class =  keywords
element tag =  ['meta']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/humor/page/...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/obvious/pag...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" href="/tag/simile/page...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<nav>\n        <ul class="pager">\n    ...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<ul class="pager">\n            \n     ...'>
element class =  pager
element tag =  ['ul']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<li class="next">\n                <a ...'>
element class =  next
element tag =  ['li']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="/page/2/">Next <span aria-hi...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span aria-hidden="true">→</span>'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="col-md-4 tags-box">\n     ...'>
element class =  col-md-4 tags-box
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<h2>Top Ten tags</h2>'>
element class =  None
element tag =  []

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 28px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 26px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 26px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 24px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 22px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 14px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 10px...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 8px"...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 8px"...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="tag-item">\n            <...'>
element class =  tag-item
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="tag" style="font-size: 6px"...'>
element class =  tag
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<footer class="footer">\n        <div ...'>
element class =  footer
element tag =  ['footer']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<div class="container">\n            <...'>
element class =  container
element tag =  ['div']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<p class="text-muted">\n              ...'>
element class =  text-muted
element tag =  ['p']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a href="https://www.goodreads.com/qu...'>
element class =  None
element tag =  ['a']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<p class="copyright">\n               ...'>
element class =  copyright
element tag =  ['p']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<span class="zyte">❤</span>'>
element class =  zyte
element tag =  ['span']

element =  <Selector query='//*' data='<a class="zyte" href="https://www.zyt...'>
element class =  zyte
element tag =  ['a']
```